# How to split part of table into 2 columns over specific number of td's with PHP?

Tags: php, html-table

The site I'm working on wants data organized in a specific way. I need to split it into two columns if it's over 8 td's long. Here is my code right now. I've put it into an array as I had an idea about doing that and using the count to display data but I haven't figured out how to make that work.

```
        $resultFound = false;
        $prevWeek = -1;
        $count = 0;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $adjustedWeek = dateToWeek($row['date']) - 35;
            if($_GET['keywords'] != "") {
                $id = search($row, $_GET['keywords']);
                if($row['id'] == $id) {
                    if($validWeek) {
                        if($week == $adjustedWeek) {
                            include('test2.php');
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        include('test2.php');
                    }
                }
            }
          foreach($tableArray as $table) {
               echo $table;
          }
```

Here is my code for test2.php

```
$table = "";
if($prevWeek != $adjustedWeek) {
    $table .= ('<th colspan=2>Week' . $adjustedWeek . '</th>');
    $prevWeek = $adjustedWeek;
}
$table .= '<tr>';
$table .= ('<td colspan=12><a href="details.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">'
    . getGameTitleText($row) . '</a></td>');
$table .= '</tr>';
$resultFound = true;
$tableArray[] = $table;
$count++;
```

I need the code to do something like this:

```
If (all items of any week > 8)
        write out 8 items to column one
        then write the rest to column two
```

I've accounted for the total number of entries it's searching but not specific to a week, and I don't want to have to make lots of variables for that either to keep track.

How could I get the result like I want?

Comment: when you say columns, do you meant a second table? Or do you mean row?

Comment: If a 2nd table would be better than that would be fine. I mean column though. The contents of week 6. Should be split to be side by side, since there are more than X results
http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/26023-1018201293739PM

Comment: It may be that I need another table though to do what i'm looking for? I am currently trying something like this

        if(($count % 8) == 0) { echo '</tr>'; }

Answer (score 0):

Warning!! the following code is to illustrate the idea only. Not tested on machine, but I think you can iron the possible error out.

pseudo code example:

```
$arr=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $arr[]['data']=$row['data'];
    $arr[]['whatever']=$row['whatever'];
}
$columns=floor(count($arr)/8);
$output="<table>";
foreach ($arr as $i=>$a){
    $output.="<tr>";
    $output.="<td>{$arr[$i]['data']}</td>";
    if ($columes>0){
        for($j=0;$j<$columes;$j++){
            $row_number=$i+($j+1)*8;
            $output.="<td>{$arr[$row_number]['data']}</td>";
        }
    }
    $output.="</tr>";
}
$output.="</table>";
```

This code will continue to add the third column if 2 is not enough.

You may still want to put a test for the end of array, so you don't get a bunch of warning when the $row_number is larger than count($arr)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it. It's a bit "dirty" because it echo's out an extra /table and /tr at the beginning but it works for my purposes and is simpler than the code already posted. That was too complex for me

```
$table = "";
if($prevWeek != $adjustedWeek) {
    $table .= '</tr></table><table class="vault_table">';
    $table .= ('<tr><th>Week ' . $adjustedWeek . '</th></tr>');
    $table .= '<table class="vault_table">';
    $prevWeek = $adjustedWeek;
}
if($count % 2 == 0) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
}
$table .= ('<td><a href="details.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">'
. getGameTitleText($row) . '</a></td>');

$resultFound = true;
$tableArray[] = $table;
$count++;
```

The class is just for styling the table. Didn't have anything to do with how it's being layed out. other than each side of the table being 50% width of the container